# Load resistance adding with minimized power and voltage constraint

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, electrical-engineering

Consider the simple circuit below:

[image]

Suppose $V$ and $R$ have set voltage and resistance values respectively, and you are to choose the resistance values for $R_1$ and $R_2$. However, you must choose $R_1$ and $R_2$ such that:

- The combined power dissipated by $R_1$ and $R_2$ is minimized
- The voltage drop across the $R_2$ resistor is as close to $V/3$ as possible

My approach is the following:

To minimize the power dissipated, we first get the power dissipated as a function of $R_1$ and $R_2$, and then get the critical points of that function.

$$I^2R=\left(\frac{V}{\sum R}\right)^2(R_1+R_2)=\frac{V^2(R_1+R_2)}{(R+R_1+R_2)^2}$$

Taking the partial derivative with respect to either $R_1$ or $R_2$, we get

$$\frac{V^2(R+R_1+R_2)-2V^2(R_1+R_2)}{(R+R_1+R_2)^3}$$

Setting that equal to zero, we find a critical point when $R_1+R_2=R$.

But we have the constraint that $IR_2\approx V/3$. If we assume equality, we get that

$$\begin{align*}
IR_2&=\left(\frac{V}{\sum R}\right)R_2\\
&=\frac{V}{3}
\end{align*}$$

Cancelling the $V$'s, we get

$$\frac{R_2}{R+R_1+R_2}=\frac{R_2}{2(R+R_2)}=\frac{1}{3}$$

$$\boxed{R_2=2R}$$

And that is where my problem is - that doesn't make sense. Could you suggest a fix to this, or maybe an alternate approach?

---

**EDIT:** As pointed out, the problem was in the "cancelling the V's" in the final step.

Is this the only way to arrive at the optimal result? Do you know of any other way?

Comment: You also made a mistake with the expression for the power, an easy way to check this is by looking at the units. It should be $\frac{V^2(R_1+R_2)}{(R+R_1+R_2)^2}$, however in this case this will lead to the same result.

Comment: 1.) Thank you @fibonatic. I was copying from my work, and I just forgot to put it there. The subsequent work was based off of the correct expression though.

2.) The reason for this being put on hold isn't valid in my opinion. I believe I showed considerable effort, and I asked for a critique of my approach and possible other approaches.

Comment: Please note that Physics.StackExchange is *not* a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just made an error in the last equation (after "Cancelling the V's"). You should get:

$$ \frac{R_2}{R+R_1+R_2} = \frac{R_2}{R+R} = \frac{R_2}{2R} = \frac{1}{3}$$

and therefore $ R_2 = \frac{2}{3}R$.